# AWS API Gateway HTTP JWT Authorizer - Google SignIn ID token verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, google-signin

I'm hosting an API using AWS API Gateway, HTTP type. I've configured a [JWT Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html) that accepts Google ID tokens. Do I need to do anything extra in the API code to verify that the ID tokens are valid?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in Google [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

> Once you get these claims, you still need to **check** that the **aud claim**
> contains one of your app's client IDs. If it does, then the **token is**
> both **valid** and intended for your client, and you can safely retrieve
> and use the user's unique Google ID from the sub claim.

According to the JWT Authorizer's docs, it does check the `aud` claim (*audience*), so I'll assume there's no need to do any further checks in the code.

Comment: Can you share how you accomplished this?